# Why Datetime being not set using v-model?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to set the value of datepicker using v-model. The js code looks like below:-

```
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
       end: "2021-03-03T20:20:00Z",
  }
})
```

And the HTML code is like below:-

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="waterEnd">End (date and time):</label>
    <input v-model="end" class="form-control" type="datetime-local" id="waterEnd" name="waterEnd">
</div>
```

I am not able to set this value but however if I print it:-

```
{{ end }}
```

Its value is rendered in the HTML page successfully.
Can anyone suggest what's being wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UTC time zone indicator (`Z`) is not allowed for the `datetime-local` input likely because the local timezone is assumed.

The seconds (`:00`) are not allowed when the input has no [`step` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#htmlattrdefstep) configured (default is `1000`, as in milliseconds). To enable seconds, set a `step` less than `1000`:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" step="1">
```

You could either remove both:

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    // end: "2021-03-03T20:20:00Z",
    end: "2021-03-03T20:20", ✅
  }
})
```

[demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/xxgZaLq)

Or configure `step` and remove only the `Z` from the string input:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" step="1" v-model="end">
```

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    // end: "2021-03-03T20:20:00Z",
    end: "2021-03-03T20:20:00", ✅
  }
})
```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/gOgPdvB)